# Orientdb - Traverse based on a specific edge field

Tags: orientdb

In the figure below each vertex is connected to others with edges of class E_FIELD. Each edge has a field called propName. Starting from a vertex I need to traverse through edges with propName set a specific value. In the figure below, I need to start from vertex 1 and traverse through the edges which have 'place' as their propName fields (going from 1 to 2 and then to 3). It should exclude vertex 4 as its propName is not set to place. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following query should help you in your quest:

```
SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE * FROM <your_vertex_rid>) WHERE @class = "E_FIELD" AND propName = "place"
```